# IE9 CSS on input button not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I am not sure how to word this but basically when in IE9, with standards and browser mode set to IE9, my button styles do not render correctly.  When in IE10 compatibility or not they look good with IE9 standards and browser mode so testing in IE10 doesn't show this error.  In chrome it works perfectly as well.  Here is my button input code and the .css as well as a fiddle that shows the button rendering.  I attached a screenshot of the button rendered in chrome (which is correct) so you can see what it should look like, i'm just not sure of a workaround for this and was hoping someone could help.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLHeD/

```
.button_standard,
.CommandButton,
.CommandButtonNoWidth,
.CommandButtonWorkflow,
.CommandButtonWorkflowNotify
{
    border-top: #F4E6CC 2px solid;
    border-right: #BFB087 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #ABA476 2px solid;
    border-left: #F5DFBA 2px solid;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin: 0;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F3D29D;
    text-decoartion: none;
    cursor:pointer; 
}

<input type="submit" name="ucDocSearchForm$btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return validateDates();" id="ucDocSearchForm_btnSearch" class="CommandButtonNoWidth" name="btnSearch" onMouseOver="this.src='/applications/images/search_over_clink.gif'" onMouseOut="this.src='/applications/images/search_on_clink.gif'" style="font-weight:bold;width:65px" />
```

[image]

Comment: Upper case kills my eyes..

Comment: that's how it was written in the style sheet that i am working on, i didn't write it myself, but i will edit the post for you, thanks for the very informative comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the order of the declarations in the `border` styles.

CSS `border` (and `border-left`, etc) are specified as [a concatenation of `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), in that order.

You've got them in a completely different order.

Theoretically, getting them in the wrong order can break things. In practice, I've not seen it actually happen very often; browsers are generally pretty good at working out what you mean in this case as the three values are easily distinguished (some other styles are more demanding in this respect, but `border` is generally less so).

However, discussions about theory and practice go out of the window here, because switching the values into the right order in your code makes it work as intended, so clearly that is the issue.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLHeD/2/

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your help with this, i didn't even think of the declaration order and you're right that other browsers including versions of IE render this correctly, but IE9 Browser mode with IE9 standards just doesn't seem to want to make it work, odd